# Is a refresh icon in an Android Toolbar considered deprecated now (did 'swipe to refresh' totally take its place)?

Tags: android, refresh, material-design, toolbar, android-toolbar

My question is more from the design point of view, related to the Material design philosophy.
So do all newest apps now completely rely on the **swipe to refresh** UX pattern when it's possible to apply it (e.g. map activities cannot have it because they take over the swipe gesture)? Is it considered too *"old-school"* to put a refresh icon in the Toolbar (in the way that this ActionBar in the picture has it)?

[image]

Because my app shows realtime statistics to the user and I would like to be sure that 90% of the users will instantly know how to refresh them.

Comment: ux.stackexhange.com *might* be better suited for these types of questions. And [there is already some discussion there](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/61229/android-swiperefreshlayout-still-a-refresh-button-in-the-menu) and [on this post which might be helpful](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/81159/android-guide-user-to-pull-to-refresh/81160#81160)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace it with `SwipeRefreshLayout`.

add this to your `xml` file:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/refreshLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/mList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

and to you `java` file this:

```
 SwipeRefreshLayout mRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.refreshLayout);

    handler.postDelayed(refreshing, 100);

    mRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            // YOUR TASK HERE.
        }
    });
```

**EDIT:**

To make user know that there's an refresh in your app you can use this to make it refresh automatically everytime app opens:

```
private Handler handler = new Handler();


private final Runnable refreshing = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        mRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
        try {
            if (mRefreshLayout.isRefreshing()) {
                // YOUR TASK HERE.
                handler.removeCallbacks(this);
            } else {
                mRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("", e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
};
```

in your task in `onPreExecute()` add this:

```
if (!mRefreshLayout.isRefreshing()) {
        mRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
 }
```

and in `onPostExecute()` add this:

```
mRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
```

> Don't forget `handler.postDelayed(refreshing, 100);` after defining the `SwipeRefreshLayout` view.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.google.de/design/spec/patterns/swipe-to-refresh.html

> Alternatively, the manual refresh method requires users to initiate content updates via an action or gesture.

Note: **an action** or gesture.

The material design guide does not prohibit the button, it simply does not give such an emphasis to it. But if it's an important action for your app, you should certainly use it.

https://www.google.com/design/icons/#ic_refresh